# XSLT Transformation not working with xsl:incldue

Tags: xslt

We are using XML/XSLT transformation using JAVA.

Here we are loading book.xlst using following URL. 
http://example.company.com/xslt/book.xslt

book.xlst internally refers to another xslincludefile.xsl using xsl:include tag.

```
  <?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="COLLECTION/BOOK">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TITLE"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AUTHOR"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PUBLISHER"/>
      <BR/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="TITLE">
  <DIV STYLE="color:blue">
    Title: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </DIV>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:include href="xslincludefile.xsl" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When we run program, it fails to load internal xslincludefile.xsl (http://example.company.com/xslt/xslincludefile.xsl) as it trying to load from local file system (file://) instead of from server (http://).

## ERROR

FATAL ERROR:  'File "file:///PATH/xslincludefile.xsl" not found.'

## Java Code

```
    InputStream ins = null;
String xslPath = "http://example.company.com/xslt/book.xslt";
File file = new File(xslPath);
String xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><COLLECTION><BOOK><TITLE>Lover Birds</TITLE><AUTHOR>Cynthia Randall</AUTHOR><PUBLISHER>Lucerne Publishing</PUBLISHER></BOOK></COLLECTION>";
javax.xml.transform.Source xslSource = null;
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlData);
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(xslPath.toString());
postMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" );

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
int status = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    ins = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    xslSource = new StreamSource(ins);
    URL url = new URL(xslPath); 
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("out.xml");
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(fos));
}
```

Are we doing anything wrong?
How can we load xslt which includes other xslt on server?

Answer (score 1):

The whole code looks very confusing with various objects being created but not being used but it looks as if you construct a StreamSource without setting the system id so use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String- e.g.

```
xslSource = new StreamSource(ins, "http://example.company.com/xslt/book.xslt");
```

That assumes you need the HttpClient and your POST request, if you simply want to load the XSLT from the URL then use `new StreamSource("http://example.company.com/xslt/book.xslt")` and create the Transformer from that Source.